# how to pass data to a component which is outside of the class

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-tab-view

I m taking username from my previous page by passing it as a parameter and I m getting the data in my new page as **this.props.userName**

Now I want to pass this value to the other component I m using in my tab view.

I m using *React Native router flux* and *react native tab view*.

Problem: since I m using constant to store the component above the class I m not able to pass the props data to that component

```
const FirstRoute = () => <Profile />;
const SecondRoute = () => <Video />;
const ThirdRoute = () => <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'}} />;

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.userName, 'props'); // want to pass this data to FirstRoute i.e: in <Profile />
    }

    state = {
        index: 1,
        routes: [
            {key: 'first', icon: 'md-contact'},
            {key: 'second', icon: 'md-videocam'},
            {key: 'third', icon: 'md-arrow-dropright-circle'},
        ],
    };

    _renderScene = SceneMap({
        first: FirstRoute,
        second: SecondRoute,
        third: ThirdRoute
    });

    render() {
        return (
            <TabView
                tabBarPosition='bottom'
                navigationState={this.state}
                renderScene={this._renderScene}
                onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange} // not included to decrease the code length
                initialLayout={initialLayout} // not included to decrease the code length
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand the `_renderScene` func as

```
_renderScene = ({ route }) => {
  switch (route.key) {
    case 'first':
      return <Profile userName={this.props.userName} />;
    case 'second':
      return <Video />;
    case 'third':
      return <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'}} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: Try the updated one as above, since you might need to pass props from FirstRoute to Profile as well.

Comment: I tried the above answer I get this error: TypeError: _this.props.renderScene is not a function

Comment: Try the updated one again, there was a typo in the name of func

Comment: Thank you very much it worked and I didn't see I was using _renderScene thanks for pointing that out too :) @Pritish